# How to install ruby interface for sqlite3 in Mac snow leopard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I tried to install it as below but it throws error :-

```
"sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby"
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/ Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

Some information about my system:-

ruby -v 1.8.7
rails -v 3.0.1
gem -v 1.3.7
sqlite3 --version 3.6.12

Also how to even check if the ruby interface for sqlite3 is installed in my system?
Like we "rails-v" to check if rails is installed in our system.I didn't find any commands over the web to check if ruby-interface for sqlite3 is installed in my system ?

Comment: Do you have XCode installed? You'll need it to compile native code. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1352406

Comment: how to check that ? Any command to check that ?

Comment: Type `gcc --version` on the command line.

Comment: yeah it is not installed . gcc--version
-bash: gcc--version: command not found.bash: gcc: command not found. How to install it in Mac. Sorry but , i'm really really new to Mac OSx !!!!

Comment: It's not too hard. I'll write an answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compile native code on OS X (such as this native Ruby extension) you have to install Apple XCode.

XCode includes various developer tools such as the clang compiler and development header files (`ruby.h` among others).

Recent version of XCode are available on the App Store. Although by default, XCode no longer installs the developers tools in a way that makes them accessible from the shell, you can fix that by installing *"Command Line Tools"* from under the Download tab of the XCode IDE preference window.

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11811515) for more details.

Comment: Even after installing the (3 GB sized)Xcode package from the above said link , gcc is not installed yet.I get "gcc command not found" when I try gcc --version. Could it be some path setting issue??

Comment: On my system /usr/bin/gcc is a symlink to /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 I'm almost certain this was create automatically by the XCode install. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810327/cant-use-gcc-in-os-x-terminal it should work at that point. Though the poster of that question fixed his problem by reinstalling XCode.

Comment: worked . .My xcode installation was not proper. Thanks it works well :)

Answer (score 0):

[Snow Leopard upgrade -> reinstalling sqlite3-ruby gem problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952853/snow-leopard-upgrade-reinstalling-sqlite3-ruby-gem-problem)

Comment: Why not just flag the question as duplicate?